# sdk for creating a remote app in azure

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net, remoteapp, azure-sdk-python

I have a Azure account.
I am able to create RemoteApp in azure using PowerShell.

I need to know whether there are SDKs available for implementing remoteapp functionality.

Kindly brief enough.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Azure SDK for Visual Studio
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/features/azure-tools-vs.aspx                                                                                                                                                                                                               .

Comment: I need sdk . and not cmdlets

Comment: can we use this for creating remoteapp on azure. Can u share some samples if available.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://i1.blogs.msdn.com/b/rds/archive/2015/03/16/introducing-remoteapp-powershell-cmdlets-and-sdk.aspx) is a link that explains how to get the `SDK`

That said, we need to add a link in our documentation center to make this easier to find, https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/services/remoteapp/